# Minecraft multiplayer: how to get rid of a bunch of ender dragons

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This is a bit embarrassing.

BACKSTORY:  I got griefed recently in my friend's multiplayer server: the offender spawned loads of Ender Dragons which attacked me, and then he kicked me out and banned me.  I've been given access again (and the offender has himself been banned).

Actual question:  I'm now back in creative mode, difficulty=peaceful, carrying on with my building.  But all the Ender Dragons are still hanging around and getting in the way - they're really distracting.  I've tried attacking them with a diamond sword but haven't managed to kill a single one yet.  There must be a command i can type to get rid of them all - is there?

EDIT - i've googled this a bit and a common solution is to do `/killall` or `/killall EnderDragon` but the `/killall` command doesn't seem to be activated on this server.

thanks, Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you've said that you haven't been able to manually kill one yet, if you give yourself a strength potion strong enough to kill the dragons with less than 1 hit (with a diamond sword) would that work for you?

Put this into a command block and then activate it (with you the closest to it)

/effect @p 5 99999 250

Also, thanks to grgarside for pointing out that this does not need to be in a command block, you can just do `/effect <your username> 5 99999 250`

Since this will cause the effect to last forever, just do `/effect <your username> 5 0` or drink some milk.

Comment: You don't need a command block to do /effect

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "put this into a command block", sorry.  Mind explaining that in a bit more detail?  thanks!

Comment: Btw, for anyone else reading this, replace "@p" with your username.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to replace @p, it works either way.

Answer (score 2):

**Use a Bukkit Plugin**

If you are on a Bukkit server, you can install a plugin called [Essentials](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/essentials/) which has a `/killall` command. Using it, you can kill mobs:

```
/killall [mob type] <radius> [world]
```

So you can kill all enderdragons using this command:

```
/killall EnderDragon 1000
```

(This will kill all ender dragons in a radius of a 1000 blocks from you)

**Edit  the world offline**

You can copy your world to your local machine and then edit it using a program like [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/). Then, go to the end dimension and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select the whole end. Then use the button `Remove Entities` to remove all entities (mobs, creatures, items ...; but no blocks).

Comment: I believe that you have to type it like this: __EnderDragon__ .

Comment: @user3487713 Your right. Sorry, wasn't paying attention.

Comment: thanks guys but `/killall EnderDragon` doesn't work - it doesn't recognise the command.

Comment: @Max_Williams Try using __/kill @e[r=10000]__ , it might kill all entities, including maybe the EnderDragon within a 10000 block radius. It might not work.

Comment: @user3487713 that will only work when using 1.8 snapshots, and can actually be narrowed with `/kill @e[type=EnderDragon]`

Comment: Oops, I kind of forgot about that.

Comment: @user3487713 - that killed me, and didn't seem to kill the dragons.  Then the server crashed, so maybe that was caused by the effect of the command kicking in, and when it comes back maybe i'll find that the dragons have gone :)